# Making listener wait javafx

Tags: java, javafx, delay

I checked some questions here but I couldn't find a proper answer. Maybe I am using wrong keywords to search. But what I found didn't help. So here is my question. I have some circles and line that are sliding in a certain way.
What I want is to update balance variable after the animations perform.

```
DoubleProperty balance = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
```

And I update the balance as follows:

```
if (shapeADone == false) {
    intersecting = arc.centerXProperty().lessThan(boldLine.getEndX() - 13);
    intersecting.addListener((obs, wasIntersecting, isNowIntersecting) -> {
        System.out.println("Collision!");
        animation1.stop();
        animation2.stop();
        animation3.stop();
    });
    again = true;
    balance.setValue(-1);
} else {
    fadeB();
    balance.setValue(1);
}
```

But in main method I want to do something like this

```
level1.balance.addListener(ov -> {
           System.out.println("The new value is " +
                   level1.balance.doubleValue());
           if (level1.balance.getValue()==1) {
              //delay setting scene
               primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
           }
       });
```

I have some animations to perform before setting scene2 but since balance instantly updating, my animations can't be performed.
I want to know if there is a way to delay listening balance or setting scene.
I tried Thread.sleep and balance.wait but it gives runtime errors.

Edit: This question clearly shows that I was lack of knowlodge about javafx. What I want to do is simple and solution is even more simple. When animation perform to the end I update the value of balance. All I wanted was make sure that animation is showed to the end.

Comment: `Making listener wait javafx` That's basically is what a `listener` is designed to do.

Comment: Just a guess here but run your animations. Then on the last/longest running animation use its `onFinish()` method to update the balance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752207/javafx-wait-for-animation-method-to-finish-before-going-to-next-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer :

```
else{
                animation3.setOnFinished(event -> balance.setValue(1));
                fadeB();
            }
```

As Sedrick's comment I change the code like this.
Adding setOnFinish to animations which need to be performed solve the problem. It's working.